# ModelError when deploying a HuggingFace model in AWS SageMaker Endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I'm trying to deploy a model using hugging face documentation in AWS SageMaker. I use the exact same code they are showing in their page:

```
from sagemaker.huggingface.model import HuggingFaceModel

# Hub model configuration <https://huggingface.co/models>
hub = {
  'HF_MODEL_ID':'distilbert-base-uncased-distilled-squad', # model_id from hf.co/models
  'HF_TASK':'question-answering'                           # NLP task you want to use for predictions
}

# create Hugging Face Model Class
huggingface_model = HuggingFaceModel(
   env=hub,                                                # configuration for loading model from Hub
   role=role,                                              # IAM role with permissions to create an endpoint
   transformers_version="4.26",                             # Transformers version used
   pytorch_version="1.13",                                  # PyTorch version used
   py_version='py39',                                      # Python version used
)

# deploy model to SageMaker Inference
predictor = huggingface_model.deploy(
   initial_instance_count=1,
   instance_type="ml.m5.xlarge"
)

# example request: you always need to define "inputs"
data = {
"inputs": {
    "question": "What is used for inference?",
    "context": "My Name is Philipp and I live in Nuremberg. This model is used with sagemaker for inference."
    }
}

# request
predictor.predict(data)
```

But when I run the code this error appears:

```
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (0) from primary with message "Your invocation timed out while waiting for a response from container primary. Review the latency metrics for each container in Amazon CloudWatch, resolve the issue, and try again.". See https://us-east-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-2#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/pytorch-inference-2023-07-02-16-57-58-277 in account {account_id} for more information.
```

I don't understand what does it mean. Can someone explain me?

Comment: I suggest taking a look at the error message in the CloudWatch logs.